# Custom SSIS dataflow Task displaying Red on error

Tags: c#, ssis

I have created a custom task dataflow task.  But when the task fails i fire.

```
ComponentMetaData.FireError(99, ComponentMetaData.Name, "General Exception: " + ex.Message, string.Empty, 0, out bout);
```

The dataflow task in the control flow does display red.  But in the Dataflow the custom task is still displaying as green even though an it incountred an error.  How do i make the Custom task display as red also.

Thanks

Comment: Fails where? Validate, during run-time?

Comment: During runtime in PrimeOutput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like I found the solution.

When you catch an exception and then do the Componentmetadata.Firerror the system no longer sees that there is a problem.  It assumes that you fixed it.

You need to rethrow an exception throw new Exception("Something Bad Happend");

Then the whole process will stop and the task will display red. It would appear that FireError just displays data in the execution results tab, it doesn't actually do anything.